# How to set the central widget of existing MainWidnow in Python PyQt4?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a code which consists of `3 classes`. The classes `widget1` and `widget2` inherit from `QFrame` class and consists of several `lineedit` and `combobox` for the user to enter information.

So, what I want is: when the program is launched, it will firstly bring up the `QMainWindow` class with `widget1` set as the `central widget`.

The `widget1` has a `Check function` which is connected to a button on it. The check button will check whether a condition is true based on the data entered by the user on the page.

If the condition is true. I want the `widget2` to set it as `central wiget` of `MainWindow` to replace existing `central widget`, the `widget1`.

My question is, how do I set the `widget2` as the central widget of existing `MainWidnow` class instance?

This is the format of my code:

```
class widget1(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        ......
        ......

    def Check(self):
       if (condition):
           #set widget2 as central widget on MainWindow

class widget2(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __int__(self,parent = None):
        .....
        .....

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        ....
        mywidgetone = widget1()
        self.setCentralWidget(mywidgetone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplicaiton(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do the following for `MainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        ....
        self.setMyCentral(widget1)

    def setMyCentral(self, widgetClass):
        mywidget = widgetClass(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(mywidget)
```

and then, in `widget1`:

```
def Check(self):
   if (condition):
       self.parent().setMyCentral(widget2)
```

Now, please, follow the conventions: classes start in capital letters (`Widget1`, `Widget2`) and methods don't (`check` instead of `Check`)

Comment: I never knew that i could use `.parent()` fucntion to access the parent object. Good to know & Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a panel creates all 3 widgets but set widget2 and 3 visible = false. Then when time to change, set widget1 visible=false, and widget2 visible. Etc. You set the panel as central widget, this never changes. Just the panel decides which one of its three children to show.