# PyQt4: central widget and parent modules

Tags: python, pyqt4

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592570/how-to-set-the-central-widget-of-existing-mainwidnow-in-python-pyqt4), except in one thing: what if classes `widget1` and `widget2` are big and I want to put them in two separate files. Problem gets in method `Check()`. So, is there a way to call `self.parent().setCentralWidget(w2)` even though `widget2` isn't in the same file as `widget1` (but they are both imported in main file containing `MainWindow`).

Code taken from [How to set the central widget of existing MainWidnow in Python PyQt4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592570/how-to-set-the-central-widget-of-existing-mainwidnow-in-python-pyqt4)

```
class widget1(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        ......
        ......

    def Check(self):
        if (condition):
            w2=widget2(self)
        self.parent().setCentralWidget(w2)

class widget2(QtGui.QFrame):
    def __int__(self,parent = None):
        .....
        .....

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        ....
        mywidgetone = widget1()
        self.setCentralWidget(mywidgetone)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplicaiton(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Please post the code of question in this post. It will be easier for us to help you.